# How to get Exception adb Error Code in C#

Tags: c#, android, shell, exception, adb

Ηow to get error exception for adb?

Like if no adb devices connected `richtextbox` give no devices connected and don't write any thing in `richtextbox`, or if device connected `richtextbox` write reading data ok then show all information about commands

this is my code :

```
// START READ INFO//
//MANFACTURE//
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        FileName = "adb.exe",
        Arguments = " shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer"
    };
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    Sks.Text = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string b = "MANUFACTURE :" + Sks.Text;
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = 15;
    progressBar1.Step = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        progressBar1.PerformStep();
    }
   // SECURITY PATCH //
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.FileName = "adb.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "shell getprop ro.build.version.security_patch";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
    Sks.Text = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string E = Environment.NewLine + "SECURITY PATCH :" + Sks.Text;
    string s = Sks.Text = b + E;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> process.StartInfo = startInfo;
> process.Start();
> process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
> Sks.Text = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
> ```

There are 2 problems here:

1. You need to redirect before you start the process
2. The error is in `StandardError`

Here is how you should do it:

```
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.Start();

Sks.Text = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
var error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // "error: no devices/emulators found"
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
{
    // do something...
}
```